# Diawi.com does not work for iOS9

Tags: xcode, ios9, ad-hoc-distribution, diawi

Until yesterday I didn't install iOS9 and on iOS8 everything was running fine. But since today, I'm (and my client for that matter) using iOS9 and I'm no longer able to deploy the app using diawi.com (which was working fine under iOS8).

Here is what happens: I click the link to install the app under iOS9, and it gives me the choice to install it or cancel. I click install, and for a second it seems to work fine (it tells me it's loading, and the loading animation on the top in the status-bar appears). But then it tells me (in German) that the app cannot be loaded (at this time).

Possible solutions I already tried:

- Turn off bitcode (didn't have any effect).
- Deploy for Ad-Hoc
- Deploy for Development
- Recompile
- Upload a second time

I need a solution to deliver the applications with an AD-Hoc Provisioning Profile using some wireless solution. If that is diawi or some other web service is not important. I'd also like a temporary workaround if one exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix has been deployed on diawi.com. It should work now for iOS 9 users (btw, Enterprise in-house app distribution on iOS 9 might now require users to trust the developer in Settings > General > Profile > Trust)

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on whether the devices you need to get your ad-hoc app onto are registered as test devices. If they are:

- Create your ad-hoc IPA file
- Upload your app (the IPA file) to a cloud hosting service in a location you can give your testers access to download from. (I personally used Dropbox when I first started but any of them will work for this.)
- Have the testers

  - Download the file
  - Open iTunes (have their device connected)
  - Drag the IPA file into the Apps library
  - Drag the app's icon onto their device
  - Sync their device

If you only have your testers' email addresses but they are all on iOS8 or higher you could always use [TestFlight beta testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html) via iTunes Connect.

**NOTE: You will have to submit the app for Beta Testing if you go this route.** This can take a similar amount of time as the App Review. You will still need to submit it for App Review later.

- Create a distribution profile with the beta entitlement
- Create an iTunes Connect Record for the App

  - Note that you can't change the app name once the record is created so don't do this if you aren't sure about that yet.
- Upload app to iTunes Connect

  - If you use Xcode, you'll need to export for submission to the app store
- Add metadata for the app
- Enable TestFlight
- Submit app for beta review
- Once the app is approved, add the names and e-mail addresses of your testers in iTunes Connect
- Send testing invitations to your testers
- Your testers will need to install the TestFlight app on their devices
- Testers will be able to install the app using the invite

Comment: I have tried submitting the app for beta testing on testing and it generally takes around 6-7 hours to get the app approved. But if you are submitting the app for app store approval then it might take around 11 days to get the approval. So, both the submission are different. For beta testing, you don't need to put much information for the app as you do for app store.

Comment: @PradeepMittal My experience with submitting for beta testing was that it took around a week, similar to getting it approved for the store. I'm sure it varies and it was faster to get updates to the app approved for beta but the first submission took at least a week.

Comment: Seems like Apple Review Team is biased lol. Anyways thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

I have just check installation process with iOS9. This way is still working with iOS9.

http://gknops.github.io/adHocGenerate/